# Adjust content in a div multiple times and store it in variables

Tags: jquery, variables

How can I adjust content in a div multiple times and store it in a variable?
In my code below, there's no difference in the four variables. It will always display the latest written content.

Can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance!

```
$("div#ingredients h1 span").html("kokos");
$("div#ingredients img").attr("src", "content/coconut.jpg");
$("div#ingredients p").html("Kokos die wij verwerken in onze Cocosballs komt uit Indonesië. De kwaliteit van die kokos draagt bij aan de heerlijke smaak van de Cocosballs.");
var coconutContent = $("div#ingredients");


$("div#ingredients h1 span").html("honing");
$("div#ingredients img").attr("src", "content/coconut.jpg");
$("div#ingredients p").html("Verse biologische honing is een onmisbaar ingrediënt in onze cocosballs, het maakt de traktatie wat frisser");
var honeyContent = $("div#ingredients");


$("div#ingredients h1 span").html("eiwit");
$("div#ingredients img").attr("src", "content/coconut.jpg");
$("div#ingredients p").html("Eiwit zorgt voor de fijne structuur van onze cocosballs en maakt ze extra luchtig");
var eggContent = $("div#ingredients");


$("div#ingredients h1 span").html("suiker"),
$("div#ingredients img").attr("src", "content/coconut.jpg"),
$("div#ingredients p").html("Het beetje suiker wat door onze Cocosballs zit, maakt onze Cocosballs af. Het wordt er wat zoeter door");
var sugarContent = $("div#ingredients");


$("div#ingredients").hide();
$(coconutContent).show();


$("#sliderButtonLeft").click(function(){

    $(sugarContent).fadeIn();

})
```

Comment: `$("div#ingredients")` returns reference to an object so here four variables referring to same jq object and IDs must be unique on document context, you'd have better to explain with concrete sample what are you looking for

Comment: I guess you want instead: `var coconutContent = $("div#ingredients").html();` etc...

Comment: Yeah I want something like that. But how can I add multiple rules of code in that variable? Like this:

`var coconutContent = $("div#ingredients h1 span").html("kokos"), $("div#ingredients img").attr("src", "content/sugar.jpg"), etc.;`

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple divs. Hide them all except the one you want to show. You're creating four variables that point to the same div, not to the varied content you want in the div.

Comment: Yeah thanks, this is the way to do it if I don't find an answer how to store it all in variables properly. I think it's more clear to put the different content in the jQuery file instead of putting it all in de HTML since I'm gonna use it for interactive purposes. Or am I wrong? I'm gone make some kind of slide show with it and the different content only need to fade in and out.